# WSO2 XSLT Mediator

Tags: xpath

Below is the sample from my sequence file

```
<log level="full">
        <property name="upsertResponse" expression="$body" scope="default"/>
</log>

<xslt description="QuerySfdcForNONcsfTransactions" key="conf:xslt/QuerySfdcForNONcsfTransactions.xslt"/>

<log level="full">
    <property name="MESSAGE" value="Before SFDC Connection 9010"/>
</log>

<salesforce.retrieve configKey="sfdc_connection">
  <fieldList>id,Opportunity_External_ID__c,Contact_External_ID__c</fieldList>
  <objectType>Opportunity</objectType>
  <objectIDS xmlns:sfdc="sfdc">{//sfdc:sObjects}</objectIDS>
</salesforce.retrieve>

<log level="full">
    <property name="MESSAGE" value="After SFDC connection here 9010"/>
</log>   

<log level="full">
    <property name="SFDCresponse" expression="$body" scope="default"/>
</log>
```

below is my xslt code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://ws.rb.com/datamodel" xmlns:sfdc="sfdc">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <sfdc:sObjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc" xmlns:ns="http://ws.rb.com/datamodel" type="Opportunity">
            <xsl:for-each select="//upsertResponse/result">
                <xsl:if test="'true' = success">
                    <sfdc:Ids>
                        <xsl:value-of select="id">
                        </xsl:value-of>
                    </sfdc:Ids>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </sfdc:sObjects>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Below is the output needed

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:Body>
<sfdc:sObjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc" xmlns:ns="http://ws.rb.com/datamodel">
<sfdc:Ids>a071a000009Ke8gAAC</sfdc:Ids>
<sfdc:Ids>006R000000954zQIAQ</sfdc:Ids>
</sfdc:sObjects>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But below is the output which i got after transformation which differs from my desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><soapenv:Header><LimitInfoHeader><limitInfo><current>21251</current><limit>5000000</limit><type>API REQUESTS</type></limitInfo></LimitInfoHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><sfdc:sObjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc" xmlns:ns="http://ws.rb.com/datamodel" type="Opportunity"></sfdc:sObjects></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

After executing the sequence below is the log file

```
WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:9d93d66d-8a60-4ecb-9a97-3fef5cb99b23, Direction: request, upsertResponse = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><upsertResponse xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><result><created>false</created><id>0061a00000BoFD0AAN</id><success>true</success></result></upsertResponse></soapenv:Body>, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><soapenv:Header><LimitInfoHeader><limitInfo><current>21251</current><limit>5000000</limit><type>API REQUESTS</type></limitInfo></LimitInfoHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><upsertResponse><result><created>false</created><id>0061a00000BoFD0AAN</id><success>true</success></result></upsertResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>



WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:9d93d66d-8a60-4ecb-9a97-3fef5cb99b23, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Before SFDC Connection 9010, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><soapenv:Header><LimitInfoHeader><limitInfo><current>21251</current><limit>5000000</limit><type>API REQUESTS</type></limitInfo></LimitInfoHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><sfdc:sObjects xmlns:sfdc="sfdc" xmlns:ns="http://ws.rb.com/datamodel" type="Opportunity"></sfdc:sObjects></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please assist me where i am wrong

Thanks